# Conversion of VB code to C#

Tags: c#, vb.net, code-translation

I'm new at C# and i would like to make my former VB program run in C# too. I got a little problem with VB's byRef, i can't translate it to C#.

So here's my code in VB:

```
Sub LepesEllenorzes(ByRef Gomb1 As Button, ByRef Gomb2 As Button)
    If Gomb2.Text = " " Then 'if a button is empty
        Gomb2.Text = Gomb1.Text 'change the numbers on them
        Gomb1.Text = " "
    End If
End Sub
```

And here's my code in C#, but doesn't working properly:

```
public Lépés(ref Button but1, ref Button but2)
{
       if (but2.Text == "")
       {
                but2.Text = but1.Text;
                but1.Text = "";
       }                
}
```

The code is from a number shuffle game, what checks, if one of the two neighbour button is empty, so the button with a number on it will change place with the empty button.

Sorry for my English, I hope you'll understand my problem.

Comment: Define "not working properly."  What indication do you have that it doesn't work as expected?

Comment: You shouldn't be using `ref` / `ByRef` at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless this is a constructor (which I highly doubt) then you need a return type.  If there's nothing being returned, `void` works:

```
public void Lépés(ref Button but1, ref Button but2)
{
        if (but2.Text == "")
        {
            but2.Text = but1.Text;
            but1.Text = "";
        }                
}
```

Second, you don't need `ref` here:

```
public void Lépés(Button but1, Button but2)
{
        if (but2.Text == "")
        {
            but2.Text = but1.Text;
            but1.Text = "";
        }                
}
```

These are reference types by default, and unless you have very specific reasons to use them you shouldn't default to `ref` parameters.

Answer (score 0):

VB is using space and C# is an empty string.  Is that it?